# ftp directory upload

Tags: ftp

I am uploading data from a hosting server to an FTP server. There are many folders inside the main folder that I'm trying to send via FTP. `put/wput` won't work for me because they only handle individual files. I am now trying `lftp` but I am getting the following issue:

```
lftp -e "mirror -R /root/temp/mail  /mail1" -u user,pass dest_ip
Getting directory contents (0) [Making data connection...]
```

It stays at "Making data connection..." but meanwhile it creates the `mail` folder on my FTP server.

How can I upload all of my folders and files to the FTP server?

Comment: Let me guess: your remote FTP server is Pureftp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're likely hung in an SSL negotation. Add `set ftp:ssl-allow off` to either your individual command or your `~/.lftprc` file. E.g.

`lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow off; mirror -R /root/temp/mail /mail1" -u user,pass dest_ip`

If you set it in your config, just know that you're keeping yourself from using any SSL encryption security features that might be on the remote host (HAW HAW HAW).

**Bonus Answer:** [scp(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

Comment: +1 for the Bonus Answer. FTP must DIE! :)

Comment: Thanks. this solution is working. actually ssh port is disabled and i cudn't use scp so only solution was to find recursive ftp upload.

Comment: @user115079 Glad to hear it's working. Don't forget to mark this as the answer when the option becomes available. It'll help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

ncftpput  supports recursive directory upload. I have used it in the past but it has been a while. check the current manual for syntax and usage.